# SSAS dimension data restriction by role advanced denied member rule

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, roles, cube

I have a Plant dimension used with multiple SSAS cube MOLAP measure groups which has 1000's of members in the dimension, each have a related region id property of 1,2,3 or 4.

The dimension is related to the measure groups by both region id & plant code, when I deselect all members for the Region Id property in the role's Dimension Data Tab and select only a few of them I end up with the below MDX in the advanced tab:

```
{[Plant].[Region Id].&[1]&[1001], [Plant].[Region Id].&[1]&[1002]}
```

This MDX is showing both the region id and plant code.

The dimension data changes each week and the members will change, I do not want to select 1000s of members to restrict these plants by Region Id for a security role, especially when these will change over time.

How can I apply a rule to restrict this data by the Region Id i.e. RegionId LIKE 1?

Comment: Can you add a new attribute to the dimension even if it's hidden? If a new attribute just had RegionID as the key you could put security on that attribute to accomplish what you want.

Comment: The dimension has a RegionID attribute already and it is hidden. I believe the reason the MDX above is using both RegionId + Plant is because that is how the dimension is linked to the measure groups.

Comment: agreed. But you can put security on one attribute and link to the measure group on another attribute. Give it a try.

Comment: @GregGalloway when applying the security on the RegionId attribute the code i supplied in the question is what it ends up with. I am looking into a way of doing this using EXISTS and FILTER in MDX to try get this to query just the RegionId value on its own.

Comment: I think you said you have a separate attribute which only has RegionID as the key (not two columns as the key). Put security on that one or add another hidden attribute with that single column key for this purpose.

Comment: @GregGalloway What I am saying is that I have a separate attribute for RegionId. When I apply the security to RegionId, the MDX that is generated is like this `[Plant].[Region Id].&[1]&[1001]` that is because 1 is the RegionId and 1001 is the PlantCode. This is due to the KEY of the dimension being RegionID + PlantCode.. I can't do what you are suggesting because I have already done that, RegionId is a hidden attribute.

Comment: Add a new attribute that's hidden called RegionIDSecurity and put security on it. The key for that attribute should be just the RegionID column

Comment: @GregGalloway I understand you, I'll give that a try, hopefully it won't apply it based on the Key when using this attribute that isn't part of the key. There are a lot of items in the dimension so I'll have to check restricting it dynamically i.e. RegionIDSecurity = 1 instead of ticking every item in the dimension.